# dynamic virtual directories and external javascript links

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

hi I have a quick question.

i have a home.aspx and inside the page in the header I have a bunch of  tags for external javascript files. My problem I am having is whenever a person adds a directory such as

```
http://localhost:444/differentnames/Home.aspx#
```

then the javascript links break and cannot be found. I've tried ../ but even that does not seem to work. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ResolveClientUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx) as so:

```
<head runat="server" id="head1"> <!-- runat="server" is important -->
  <script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>' />
```

Where `~` is the App root directory. `ResolveClientUrl` will take care of resolving the path appropriately no matter how nested is the page.

Comment: @user1084319 like this: `<script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>' type="text/javascript" />`

Comment: do I just put it around all my source's? or do i have to do it to my link hrefs as well?

Comment: @user1084319 anything that may brake due to a change in the path: images, script references, css files, etc...

Comment: mm I still seem to have a problem, I surrounded all my script src = with what you said however, on the website when i try to run it an empty block just appears and the content doesn't seem to show

Answer (score 0):

try to load your references via the Pae_Init method.

It can be done with the Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScriptInclude() method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2552td66